# Eclipse/Java 9: How to get e(fx)clipse 3.7.0 to work?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

Preface: I already have the latest version of Eclipse installed and have been using it without issue. I'm running into issues now, as we are supposed to implement JavaFX into future projects.

Here are the instructions I was given to follow:

> Installing JavaFX If you have the latest version of Eclipse installed
> on your machine:
>
> 1. In Eclipse, go to Help, Eclipse MarketPlace
> 2. Search for “javafx” in the “Find” bar
> 3. Click on “install” next to the “e(fx)clipse 3.7.0
> 4. If a message pops up indicating an error, it is because you have other packages which will be overridden – this is OK, confirm these
>    updates.
> 5. Restart Eclipse when prompted
>
> Creating a JavaFX Project In Eclipse, New > Project > JavaFX > JavaFX
> Project

Now, I have followed all of the above steps and I am unable to do anything as the default Main.java fails to compile and run due to the following error:

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
> java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found

Now, there are a lot of red underlines in the code, and I'm pretty confident it has to do with the JavaFX libraries not being available.

I have googled and followed other sets of instructions from Stack Overflow and other resources, but they all pretty much deal with Java SE 11 and higher, and we are required to use Java SE 9.

Here is my current buildpath. Although the instructions were referring to Java SE 11, I did install some JavaFX .jar files and uploaded them under classpath as well ( not currently pictured as I removed them when it didn't fix the issue ).

[image]

I saw another set of instructions that said to edit the isModular setting under the JRE for Java 9, but when I typed in "javafx.controls" under the source module to add exports, it tells me "Module 'javafx.controls" is not provided by this build path entry.

Comment: If Java 9 is the max version you are allowed to use for your project and you are having difficulty finding a development environment which supports it, switch to Java/JavaFX 8 (if that is allowed) instead.  Version 8 is more likely to be well supported by IDEs than the Java 9 version.  The issue you are getting is related to Java/JavaFX platform modularization, which wasn't implemented in Java 8, so switching to Java 8 might just resolve your issue.  Of course, if it must be Java 9 and only Java 9, this comment will not help you.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the feedback, and yeah, it would be a lot easier if we could roll back to 8. Unfortunately, it's a no.

Comment: I suggest that you contact whoever is setting the requirements for your project and request that the requirements are updated to use modern software.

Comment: I would prefer switching to jdk 8 or 11 and above. If it's not possible, then

Add this to VM Options.
--module-path /path/to/JavaFX/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who attempted to help, I was able to get it to work and so I'll post the solution for anyone else who might run into this rare situation.

```
1. Install JDK 9.0.4 from Oracle.
2. Install Eclipse
3. Run Eclipse
4. Install e(fx)clipse 3.7.0
   - Click Help > Eclipse Marketplace
   - Search "JavaFX"
   - Click "Install" on e(fx)clipse 3.7.0
5. Install JDK 9.0.4 in Eclipse
   - Window > Preferences
   - Search "Installed"
   - Select "Installed JREs"
   - Click "Add"
   - Select "Standard VM"
   - Click "Directory" 
   - Find the JDK Folder, "jdk-9.0.4" and Select It 
   - Click "Select Folder" Click "Finish"
6. Create a new JavaFX Project
   - File > New > Project
   - JavaFX > JavaFX Project
   - Ensure JavaSE-9 is selected next to "Use an executed environment JRE:"
   - Click "Finish"
7. Configure Build Path
   - Right-click on Project
   - Build Path > Configure Build Path
   - Ensure Libraries is selected along the top row
   - Click JavaFX SDK under Modulepath
   - Click "Remove"
   - Click "Classpath"
   - Click "Add Libary..."
   - Select "JavaFX SDK"
   - Click "Next"
   - Click "Finish"
   - Select "JRE System Library [JavaSE-9]"
   - Click "Remove"
   - Click "Classpath"
   - Click "Add Library..."
   - Select "JRE System Library"
   - Select either "Execution Environment: "JavaSE-9 (jre-9.0.4)" OR "Workspace default JRE (jre-9.0.4)
   - Click Finish
8. Remove "Module-info.java"
   - Expand your Project Folders in the "Package Explorer"
   - Right-click on "Module-info.java"
   - Click "Delete"
```